# Pass all needed values with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two table to print values from database. Then I use script to select specific cells from row.
That part works well. Then I have created bootstrap modal, and I have to retrieve values from modal also and insert all values in database.
Script I use to select specific cells in different rows.

```
<script>
    $(".addValues").click(function () {
          $('#selection').show();
            var $this = $(this),
            myCol = $this.closest("td"),
            myRow = myCol.closest("tr"),
            targetArea = $("#selection");

            var qte_input = (' <input type="text" name="kolicina" id="kolicina" placeholder="kg / m" size="10"/>');
              targetArea.prepend($("td.data-id", myRow).text() + qte_input +"<hr />"); 
          });
</script>
```

html code

```
<td class='data-id'><?='B-'. $r['Id']?> </td>
```

Selected values print in another div

```
<div id="selection">                               
</div>
```

Second script get values from modal, script works good.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#myFormSubmit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

       var x = document.getElementById("kolicina").value;
       var y = document.getElementById("sifra").value;     
       var f = document.getElementById("firma").value;
       var k = document.getElementById("kontakt").value;
       var a = document.getElementById("adresa").value;
       var t = document.getElementById("tel").value;
       var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
       var n = document.getElementById("napomena").value;

       var kolicina = {kolicina:x};
       var sifra = {sifra:y};

       var firma = {firma:f};
       var kontakt = {kontakt:k};
       var adresa = {adresa:a};
       var tel = {tel:t};
       var email = {email:e};
       var napomena = {napomena:n};

       $.ajax({ url: 'materijali-script.php',
    data: arr,
    type: 'post',
    });
    });
</script>
```

I got all needed values from second script (from modal). I need to get selected values from first script. Those values should be in array where every selection will hold who values Id and quantity.
Could someone give me advice how I can send all needed values

Here on the image, for example values are selected from table, then added value after.[image]

I want to pass all values from the image together with values from modal

Comment: pass all crucial variables into `data` parameter in `ajax` request

Answer (score 0):

You may useful below code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#myFormSubmit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

       var x = document.getElementById("kolicina").value;
       var y = document.getElementById("sifra").value;
       var f = document.getElementById("firma").value;
       var k = document.getElementById("kontakt").value;
       var a = document.getElementById("adresa").value;
       var t = document.getElementById("tel").value;
       var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
       var n = document.getElementById("napomena").value;

       var kolicina = {kolicina:x};
       var sifra = {sifra:y};

       var firma = {firma:f};
       var kontakt = {kontakt:k};
       var adresa = {adresa:a};
       var tel = {tel:t};
       var email = {email:e};
       var napomena = {napomena:n};

       var arr=[];
       arr.push(
                {"kolicina":document.getElementById("kolicina").value},
                {"sifra":document.getElementById("sifra").value},
                {"firma":document.getElementById("firma").value},
                {"kontakt":document.getElementById("kontakt").value}
           );

       $.ajax({ url: 'materijali-script.php',
    data: arr,
    type: 'post',
    });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: The problem is that  var x = document.getElementById("kolicina").value;
var y = document.getElementById("sifra").value; are empty it does not pass them from first script. In first script I get them and I was wondering how to pass those values in second script and process  them

Comment: you need to take global variables.

Comment: Please refer to question now, I have added image. On the image you see selected values and "Pošalji Zahtjev" button. Once I click button it opens modal, I fill needed information then I have to process all values from modal and selected together

Comment: please elaborate more.